# How to implement Draggable Bottom Sheet Modal in svelte?

Tags: javascript, animation, svelte

How to achieve the dragging effect?

example bottom sheet modal Maps:
https://preview.redd.it/l9aos22q0sr51.gif?format=mp4&s=745a5f3a940436941610e36e3d2242f367803e71

Comment: The link is just a video showing the desired effect, which is Dragging a div element and expanding it, maybe using spring animations? idk how to achieve that in svelte

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post what you have done so far. 
If you need help please use the following guide stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just used this: https://github.com/roman-rr/cupertino-pane ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

Answer (score 0):

Svelte tutorials has a nice introduction to handling mouse events using actions. Check out the [actions tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/actions).

Using this same actions here is a [vertical splitter](https://svelte.dev/repl/3fd400eafc8240d8b8f834aace706e9b?version=3.29.0) on the svelte REPL.

Comment: I managed to edit this so far
https://svelte.dev/repl/f8d942a2cff64fbda44d6cc97b1ee754?version=3.29.0
But can't connect it with action/spring animations

Comment: Also, I can't figure out how to make slide all the way up/down like in the video, I have to drag it all the way.